# Distributed Powerset

Tags: python, algorithm, distributed, powerset

Considering the *powerset* operation (generate all possible subsets of a given set) and its massiveness (time complexity of O(n*2^n) ), I'm trying to scale it horizontally (distributed solution). Don't know if this is easily achievable (hence the question), but I'll try to break down the problem and make it as clear as possible.

Consider the following example using python:

```
import itertools

s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for l in range(1, len(s)+1):   # this can be distributed

    for subset in itertools.combinations(s, l):
        print(subset)
```

It's possible (and easy) to distribute the workload based on the subsets length. For instance, if we have a set of length 5, we can make each worker calc all subsets of length N - in this case we would have 5 workers.
Why this doesn't appeal to me is quite obvious - workload distribution is not balanced at all. A set of length 20 will generate 184756 subsets of length 10 and only 20 subsets of length 1 (this means that the middle workers will always have a lot more processing to do).

**Question**

Is there a way to distribute the workload linearly in this case, and how? Rephrasing the problem - for a set of length L can I distribute the work to compute the powerset using N well balanced workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use n bits of an integer to represent the items in a subset of n items, you can start the variable at 0, and increment it to get to the next subset.  So to evenly distribute the work between k processors, you can simply have processor #i start its integer variable at i and add k to it on each step.  Every subset will be processed by exactly one processor.

Bear in mind that this won't do very much to help you solve large problems.  If you can solve a problem of size x on a single computer (and I'd estimate 20 <= x <= 30 on today's computers, roughly), then even by buying 1024 computers you would only be able to solve a problem of size x+10.

Comment: Good point, using n bits to generate the powerset is quite easy and can be divided/balanced effortlessly! (I'll wait a bit for more answers and if there are none better I'll accept this one)

Comment: This is the "more balanced ways to go" version that I suggested.  Do note that when you're distributing across the cloud, different machines will have unpredictably different performance based on what else that machine is doing.  Therefore it probably makes sense to make more jobs than machines and give each machine as many jobs as it gets through.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not a good way to solve the problem.  Exponential growth means that the number of needed machines will grow exponentially as well.  In virtually every case, the right answer is, "Figure out how not to compute the power set."

That said, here is the simplest way to break things up.  Take the first 'x' elements, and compute all of the subsets of those things.  This gives you '2^x' jobs. Distribute those jobs to `y` machines relatively evenly.  Each machine finishes computing subsets for each job and produces output.

As a further optimization, distribute jobs as workers finish.  That way if some workers are running slowly, you'll keep everyone working until you finish.

(There are more balanced ways to go, but they involve worrying about what your powerset algorithm is.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot avoid computing the powerset because it is a central piece in the problem I'm solving.

Comment: @joao In that case, I would suggest you split this problem into halves.  Calculate the powerset of the first half of the elements, and the powerset of the second half.  Then have jobs to create chunks of the powerset by just sending a specific first half-powerset with every combination in the second half.  Because you're just combining, there is now no logic on generating power sets.